# Label or instruction expected at start of line

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, nasm

I cannot figure out what is wrong. I am compiling with `nasm -f elf main.S`

```
use32
section .text
global  _start


_start: mov     eax, 0
        mov     ebx, 0
        ecx     5

label1: inc     eax
        add     ebx, ecx
        loop    label1

exit:   mov     eax, 1      ; sys_exit syscall
        mov     ebx, 0      ; return 0 (success)
        int     80h
```

main.S:8: error: label or instruction expected at start of line

Line 8 - ecx 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ecx     5` is not an instruction. Did you mean `mov ecx,5` ?

Comment: :) Thank you. I should be more careful.